# Find the value of $x$ for which $ff=gf$.

Tags: functions, relations

Functions $f$ and $g$ are defined by $f:x \mapsto \frac{1}{2x+1}$, $x \neq \frac{-1}{2}$ and $g:x \mapsto x+1$. Find the value of $x$ for which $ff=gf$.

So I started in this way:

$f[f(x)]=g[f(x)]$

$f(\frac{1}{2x+1}) = g(\frac{1}{2x+1})$

$\frac{1}{2(\frac{1}{2x+1})+1}=\frac{1}{2x+1}+1$

Then I solve it in simple algebra. Is this right?

I get the wrong answer, my book says $\frac{-5}{6}$ but I get $\frac{-11}{2}$

Helppp

Comment: Do you mean $f \cdot f = g \cdot f$ or $f \circ f = g \circ f$?

Comment: @NigelOvermars What does that mean?

Comment: @NigelOvermars I guess I just had to substitute the correct values and simply solve it!

Comment: The product of the functions of the composition?

Comment: Then you mean the composition, $(g \circ f)(x) = g(f(x))$.

Comment: @NigelOvermars How would you solve the question? In your way tell if it is wrong and why.

Comment: @NigelOvermars my book showed an example in this way...

Comment: The algebraic steps might be simpler (and thus "stupid" errors avoided), by first solving $f(y)=g(y)$ for $y$ and then find $x$ with $y=f(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{1}{2(\frac{1}{2x+1})+1}=\frac{1}{2x+1}+1 \Leftrightarrow$

$\frac{2x+1}{2x+3}=\frac{2x+2}{2x+1}\Leftrightarrow$

$(2x+1)^2=(2x+2)(2x+3) \Leftrightarrow$

$4x^2+4x+1=4x^2+10x+6 \Leftrightarrow$

$6x+5=0$. So $x=-\frac{5}{6}$. Your book is right.

Answer (score 2):

When I solve exactly what you wrote on your last line algebraically, I get -5/6. I suspect you made a simple mistake.